# Course has many students and many students belong to one course. How to find to which course a particular student belong?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

there is a one to many unidirectional mapping from course to students

```
@Entity
Course {
@OnetoMany
List<Student> students;
}
```

```
@Entity
Student {
name;
age;
}
```

the database schema looks like
Course
id name duration fee

Student
rollno name age course_id

I am using Jpa repository for getting.

Can anyone please tell how to tell in which course a particular student belong to? Please note that i am not using bi-directioal mapping so student entity class has no reference to course.

Comment: Are you sure your design should force a student to have one and only one course? This schema and java model means you cannot just associate a student to a course without risk of changing an existing course->Student relationship without knowing it. Making this bidirectional at least will give your code that indication, and so know that it is replacing the student->Course with something else if it is mapped there (and you can put in optimistic locking if concurrent changes becomes an issue). This model looks good for data dumps, where the student entries are just raw data that are maintained

Comment: This database is designed from a university perspective. So a student at a time can be enrolled in only one course, by course I mean B.tech, M.tech, phd etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mappings and DB schema are fine, and there is nothing overly special about your mapping situation - it is just a unidirectional mapping, and there is no need for force mapping it bidirectionally and/or fetching the student data if you don't need it.

JPQL: "Select c from Course c join c.students s where s.name = :name"

With spring boot

```
@Query("Select c from Course c join c.students s where s.name = ?1")
Course findCourseByStudentName(String name);
```

Your DB setup would need to be looked at to determine if the Course is unique - I'd guess it isn't, in which case you'll want to return a list of courses that might have this student name registered.

Comment: A particular course can have many students and each student can enroll in only one course at a time. And multiple students can enroll in the same course. I think my database design is perfect for this use case.

Comment: For the purpose of this answer, I was suggesting that student name might not be unique. You didn't show what uniquely identifies a student in your entity, and it might not be name (you mentioned it has a rollno, but didn't show its mapping), so this example query might bring up multiple courses - a list - and not a single course instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the database deign. No performant code will rescue you from that fate.

Typically there is a join table between Students and Courses that minimally maintains two keys - the studentId and the courseId.

Need to know the courses for a student? Select from the join table where studentId = ‘X’. Need to know students in a course? Select from the join table where courseId = ‘Y’.

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment on the DB design. But solution for this problem is simple.

Basically you need to implement the relationship correctly.

```java
@Entity
public class Course {
  private Long id;

  @OnetoMany(mappedBy = "course")
  List<Student> students;
}

@Entity
public class Student {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Integer age;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
  private Course course;
}
```

Then simply use the getter

```java
  Student student = studentRepo.findStudentById(123);
  Course course = student.getCourse();
```

Here is the full reference: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But previously I was using the same bidirectional relationship but when we fetch an entity it gives an infinite recursion error. Please search for this error on internet, you'll get to know. After that I changed it to unidirectional.

Comment: That will never happen if done correctly. Please cross check the annotations and dependencies correctly and make sure that you have enabled lazy fetch. And little correction, it is not a bidirectional relationship. It is still One-To-Many unidirectional relationship with JPA referencing to parent. So do try out the solution I shared above as is without any changes to annotations and check if it works.